# multiplying fields values

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

Hi can someone help me with some field maths. I have taxonomy vocabulary called "plast" with several terms (large box, small box etc.) i have created field within the taxonomy called weight which is linked to each term. Now i have a nod where the user selects term from the taxonomy "plastic"and in the next field enters amount, what i want is to show i the next field "total weight" is weight from the taxonomy term multiplied by the amount.

thanks

Comment: I think that jquery is your friend here to do the calculations on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think there must be an easer way using views so if  have taxonomy term "small box" which has a field "weight" linked to it with defaolt value 0.6  the folowing field in my nod is "amount" how do i get the result in views so i would see 0.6 multiplied by the "amount"

Thanks